create a picture in your mind that you achieved

It appears that the secret to achieving what you really want in life is to write down specifically what you most desire. Create a picture in your mind that you have achieved those goals.

Source: https://www.saltwire.com/prince-edward-island/business/joe-sherren-change-your-thinking-change-your-life-296297/

Create in your mind a picture that you have achieved those goals.

"in your mind" could be moved before "a picture", so this makes me think that "in your mind" might not be included in what "that" refers to.
Is "in my mind" part of what "that" refers to?

What's your point?
Changing the position of the direct object and prepositional phrase does not affect the relative clause. Certain orders are allowed in English.

"A picture... that" is a rather unusual expression. He means "a picture of what your life would be like if you had achieved your goals".

In general, the antecedent of a pronoun is the closest preceding noun phrase for which it makes sense to use it.
It doesn't make sense for "that you have achieved these goals" to refer to "your mind", so the antecedent can't be "mind".
However, it does make sense for it to refer to "a picture". It describes what the picture contains, just as "in your mind" describes where the picture exists. So "that" refers to "picture".

Is the antecedent of "that" "a picture in your mind" or just "a picture"?

Both. "picture" is the head noun of the noun phrase "a picture in your mind".
